# Yorkshire Puddings with Fish in Sauce

Tags: yorkshire-puddings

What is the reason that Yorkshire Puddings are considered to only be served with roast beef / or perhaps as the batter for Toad-in-the-hole? (NB For non-UK residents, this is a baked dish consisting of sausages enrobed in Yorkshire Pudding batter.)

Background: I'm considering using a single large Yorkshire Pudding as the vessel to contain fish fillets in a creamy, buttery sauce.  Should I be dissuaded?  If so, for what reason(s)?

I await your answers with battered breath.

Comment: What is the shortening in your Yorkshire pudding?

Comment: I'm afraid this is really just a "pairing" question. You can put anything you like in a Yorkie, from sozzies to chilli con carne.

Comment: @Willk "Shortening" is not a term I'm really used to using.  The fat in my Yorkies comes from the milk (full fat, blue top, whole milk), plus the oil (olive) that I bake them in.

Answer (score 2):

This has made me so hungry I came back down to write!

1:  Yes!  But I would not use roast drippings or suet as shortening for fear of overwhelming the fish with beef.  Anything else.  Duck fat would be lovely.  Lard or vegetable shortening or butter ok.  It might not be as stiff with butter.

2:  Have sauce added by diner on top right before eating or it will sog out the pudding.

3:  What deserves to be in with the fish?  Leek or carrot or parsley all very precious and would be visually spectacular.  But thinking @bob1 deconstructed fish and chips... what do you put on fish and chips?  Vinegar.  What wont soak the pudding but is vinegary and has some veg crunch.  **A pickle!**  A pickle spear in there with the fish would be perfect!

I was thinking also some of those crunchy premade onions like Frenchs makes for salad and hot dish but that is my belly talking.  You could have those on the side for the Americans to sprinkle on.

Comment: Thank you @Willk for your frabjous answer ;)  Great advice re #1, and definitely agree with late application of sauce per your #2.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why you couldn't do this. It would be equivalent to having a battered fish fillet as a part of your fish-and-chips. This is presuming that you are planning on cooking the batter, then adding the fish and sauce, or perhaps cooking the batter and fish, *a la* toad-in-the-hole, then adding sauce.

You definitely won't be able to cook the sauce in the batter as it will dilute the batter and the batter won't reach temperature fast enough to rise properly and get crisp.

Comment: Thanks @bob1, to confirm, I will be cooking the batter separately, then adding the fish-in-sauce into the battery container.  Any tips on herbs and spices to add to the batter mix?

Comment: bob1: on re-reading your comment, I realise something: this *wouldn't* be equivalent to having a battered fish fillet, because I'm not battering it.

Comment: @ro͢binmckenzie - I was thinking more a long the lines of a "deconstructed" battered fish - this might even make it high cuisine, being all trendy and the like ;)
Perhaps a nice bit of tarragon would go well. I think you'd be best to add the herbs/spices to the sauce and leave the batter as contrast. If you were to add to the batter I think best to use dried herbs/spices.

Comment: deconstructed battered fish is exactly right, and I'm totally with you per tarragon.